# Drawing Custom WaveForm views in each listview items

Tags: android, listview, audio

***What I am doing***

- I am having multiple audio files Playing them in listview.
- On each List view item I am drawing the custom waveform of particular audio file  on that postion.
- Each audio files are first read by Meta Data reader and after that they are converting it into waveform view.

***What is my issue.***

- The wave form is generated only on the last list item View rest all are empty view. And also the wave form of each sound file is generated on last list item view only.

***Here is my code below***

***Waveform View class***

```
public class WaveformView extends View {
    public interface WaveformListener {
        public void waveformTouchStart(float x);

        public void waveformTouchMove(float x);

        public void waveformTouchEnd();

        public void waveformFling(float x);

        public void waveformDraw();
    }


    // Colors
    private Paint mGridPaint;
    private Paint mSelectedLinePaint;
    private Paint mUnselectedLinePaint;
    private Paint mUnselectedBkgndLinePaint;
    private Paint mBorderLinePaint;
    private Paint mPlaybackLinePaint;
    private Paint mTimecodePaint;

    private SoundFile mSoundFile;
    private int[] mLenByZoomLevel;
    private double[][] mValuesByZoomLevel;
    private double[] mZoomFactorByZoomLevel;
    private int[] mHeightsAtThisZoomLevel;
    private int mZoomLevel;
    private int mNumZoomLevels;
    private int mSampleRate;
    private int mSamplesPerFrame;
    private int mOffset;
    private int mSelectionStart;
    private int mSelectionEnd;
    private int mPlaybackPos;
    private float mDensity;
    private float mInitialScaleSpan;
    private WaveformListener mListener;
    private GestureDetector mGestureDetector;
    private ScaleGestureDetector mScaleGestureDetector;
    private boolean mInitialized;
      Color color;
    int totalLines = 0;
    MainActivity mainActivity;


    public WaveformView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        // We don't want keys, the markers get these
        setFocusable(false);

        mGridPaint = new Paint();
        mGridPaint.setAntiAlias(false);
        mGridPaint.setColor(
                getResources().getColor(R.color.grid_line));
        mSelectedLinePaint = new Paint();
        mSelectedLinePaint.setAntiAlias(false);
        mSelectedLinePaint.setColor(
                getResources().getColor(R.color.waveform_selected));
        mUnselectedLinePaint = new Paint();
        mUnselectedLinePaint.setAntiAlias(false);
        mUnselectedLinePaint.setColor(
                getResources().getColor(R.color.waveform_unselected));
        mUnselectedBkgndLinePaint = new Paint();
        mUnselectedBkgndLinePaint.setAntiAlias(false);
        mUnselectedBkgndLinePaint.setColor(
                getResources().getColor(
                        R.color.selection_border));
        mBorderLinePaint = new Paint();
        mBorderLinePaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mBorderLinePaint.setStrokeWidth(1.5f);
        mBorderLinePaint.setPathEffect(
                new DashPathEffect(new float[]{3.0f, 2.0f}, 0.0f));
        mBorderLinePaint.setColor(
                getResources().getColor(R.color.selection_border));
        mPlaybackLinePaint = new Paint();
        mPlaybackLinePaint.setAntiAlias(false);
        mPlaybackLinePaint.setColor(
                getResources().getColor(R.color.playback_indicator));
        mTimecodePaint = new Paint();
        mTimecodePaint.setTextSize(12);
        mTimecodePaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mTimecodePaint.setColor(
                getResources().getColor(R.color.timecode));
        mTimecodePaint.setShadowLayer(
                2, 1, 1,
                getResources().getColor(R.color.timecode_shadow));

        mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(
                context,
                new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
                    public boolean onFling(
                            MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float vx, float vy) {
                        mListener.waveformFling(vx);
                        return true;
                    }
                });

        mSoundFile = null;
        mLenByZoomLevel = null;
        mValuesByZoomLevel = null;
        mHeightsAtThisZoomLevel = null;
        mOffset = 0;
        mPlaybackPos = -1;
        mSelectionStart = 0;
        mSelectionEnd = 0;
        mDensity = 1.0f;
        mInitialized = false;
    }


    public boolean hasSoundFile() {
        return mSoundFile != null;
    }

    public void setSoundFile(SoundFile soundFile) {
        mSoundFile = soundFile;
        mSampleRate = mSoundFile.getSampleRate();
        mSamplesPerFrame = mSoundFile.getSamplesPerFrame();
        computeDoublesForAllZoomLevels();
        mHeightsAtThisZoomLevel = null;
    }

    /**
     * Called once when a new sound file is added
     */
    private void computeDoublesForAllZoomLevels() {
        int numFrames = mSoundFile.getNumFrames();
        int[] frameGains = mSoundFile.getFrameGains();
        double[] smoothedGains = new double[numFrames];
        if (numFrames == 1) {
            smoothedGains[0] = frameGains[0];
        } else if (numFrames == 2) {
            smoothedGains[0] = frameGains[0];
            smoothedGains[1] = frameGains[1];
        } else if (numFrames > 2) {
            smoothedGains[0] = (double)(
                    (frameGains[0] / 2.0) +
                            (frameGains[1] / 2.0));
            for (int i = 1; i < numFrames - 1; i++) {
                smoothedGains[i] = (double)(
                        (frameGains[i - 1] / 3.0) +
                                (frameGains[i    ] / 3.0) +
                                (frameGains[i + 1] / 3.0));
            }
            smoothedGains[numFrames - 1] = (double)(
                    (frameGains[numFrames - 2] / 2.0) +
                            (frameGains[numFrames - 1] / 2.0));
        }

        // Make sure the range is no more than 0 - 255
        double maxGain = 1.0;
        for (int i = 0; i < numFrames; i++) {
            if (smoothedGains[i] > maxGain) {
                maxGain = smoothedGains[i];
            }
        }
        double scaleFactor = 1.0;
        if (maxGain > 255.0) {
            scaleFactor = 255 / maxGain;
        }

        // Build histogram of 256 bins and figure out the new scaled max
        maxGain = 0;
        int gainHist[] = new int[256];
        for (int i = 0; i < numFrames; i++) {
            int smoothedGain = (int)(smoothedGains[i] * scaleFactor);
            if (smoothedGain < 0)
                smoothedGain = 0;
            if (smoothedGain > 255)
                smoothedGain = 255;

            if (smoothedGain > maxGain)
                maxGain = smoothedGain;

            gainHist[smoothedGain]++;
        }

        // Re-calibrate the min to be 5%
        double minGain = 0;
        int sum = 0;
        while (minGain < 255 && sum < numFrames / 20) {
            sum += gainHist[(int)minGain];
            minGain++;
        }

        // Re-calibrate the max to be 99%
        sum = 0;
        while (maxGain > 2 && sum < numFrames / 100) {
            sum += gainHist[(int)maxGain];
            maxGain--;
        }

        // Compute the heights
        double[] heights = new double[numFrames];
        double range = maxGain - minGain;
        for (int i = 0; i < numFrames; i++) {
            double value = (smoothedGains[i] * scaleFactor - minGain) / range;
            if (value < 0.0)
                value = 0.0;
            if (value > 1.0)
                value = 1.0;
            heights[i] = value * value;
        }

        mNumZoomLevels = 5;
        mLenByZoomLevel = new int[5];
        mZoomFactorByZoomLevel = new double[5];
        mValuesByZoomLevel = new double[5][];

        // Level 0 is doubled, with interpolated values
        mLenByZoomLevel[0] = numFrames * 2;
        mZoomFactorByZoomLevel[0] = 2.0;
        mValuesByZoomLevel[0] = new double[mLenByZoomLevel[0]];
        if (numFrames > 0) {
            mValuesByZoomLevel[0][0] = 0.5 * heights[0];
            mValuesByZoomLevel[0][1] = heights[0];
        }
        for (int i = 1; i < numFrames; i++) {
            mValuesByZoomLevel[0][2 * i] = 0.5 * (heights[i - 1] + heights[i]);
            mValuesByZoomLevel[0][2 * i + 1] = heights[i];
        }

        // Level 1 is normal
        mLenByZoomLevel[1] = numFrames;
        mValuesByZoomLevel[1] = new double[mLenByZoomLevel[1]];
        mZoomFactorByZoomLevel[1] = 1.0;
        for (int i = 0; i < mLenByZoomLevel[1]; i++) {
            mValuesByZoomLevel[1][i] = heights[i];
        }

        // 3 more levels are each halved
        for (int j = 2; j < 5; j++) {
            mLenByZoomLevel[j] = mLenByZoomLevel[j - 1] / 2;
            mValuesByZoomLevel[j] = new double[mLenByZoomLevel[j]];
            mZoomFactorByZoomLevel[j] = mZoomFactorByZoomLevel[j - 1] / 2.0;
            for (int i = 0; i < mLenByZoomLevel[j]; i++) {
                mValuesByZoomLevel[j][i] =
                        0.5 * (mValuesByZoomLevel[j - 1][2 * i] +
                                mValuesByZoomLevel[j - 1][2 * i + 1]);
            }
        }

        if (numFrames > 5000) {
            mZoomLevel = 3;
        } else if (numFrames > 1000) {
            mZoomLevel = 2;
        } else if (numFrames > 300) {
            mZoomLevel = 1;
        } else {
            mZoomLevel = 0;
        }

        mInitialized = true;
    }

    public boolean canZoomIn() {
        return (mZoomLevel > 0);
    }

    public void zoomIn() {
        if (canZoomIn()) {
            mZoomLevel--;
            mSelectionStart *= 2;
            mSelectionEnd *= 2;
            mHeightsAtThisZoomLevel = null;
            int offsetCenter = mOffset + getMeasuredWidth() / 2;
            offsetCenter *= 2;
            mOffset = offsetCenter - getMeasuredWidth() / 2;
            if (mOffset < 0)
                mOffset = 0;
            invalidate();
        }
    }

    public boolean canZoomOut() {
        return (mZoomLevel < mNumZoomLevels - 1);
    }

    public void zoomOut() {
        if (canZoomOut()) {
            mZoomLevel++;
            mSelectionStart /= 2;
            mSelectionEnd /= 2;
            int offsetCenter = mOffset + getMeasuredWidth() / 2;
            offsetCenter /= 2;
            mOffset = offsetCenter - getMeasuredWidth() / 2;
            if (mOffset < 0)
                mOffset = 0;
            mHeightsAtThisZoomLevel = null;
            invalidate();
        }
    }



    public void setParameters(int start, int end, int offset) {
        mSelectionStart = start;
        mSelectionEnd = end;
        mOffset = offset;
    }

    public int getStart() {
        return mSelectionStart;
    }

    public int getEnd() {
        return mSelectionEnd;
    }

    public int getOffset() {
        return mOffset;
    }

    public void setPlayback(int pos) {
        mPlaybackPos = pos;
    }

    public void setListener(WaveformListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
    }

    public void recomputeHeights(float density) {
        mHeightsAtThisZoomLevel = null;
        mDensity = density;
        mTimecodePaint.setTextSize((int)(12 * density));

        invalidate();
    }


    protected void drawWaveformLine(Canvas canvas,
                                    int x, int y0, int y1,
                                    Paint paint) {
        canvas.drawLine(x, y0, x, y1, paint);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        if (mSoundFile == null)
            return;

        if (mHeightsAtThisZoomLevel == null)
            computeIntsForThisZoomLevel();
        DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        int height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
        int widths = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
        // Draw waveform
        int measuredWidth = getMeasuredWidth();
        int measuredHeight = getMeasuredHeight();
        int start = mOffset;
        int width = mHeightsAtThisZoomLevel.length - start;
        int ctr = measuredHeight / 2;


        totalLines = width;

        Log.e("wid",String.valueOf(width));
        Log.e("widCal",String.valueOf(mHeightsAtThisZoomLevel.length));
        Log.e("widstart",String.valueOf(start));


        if (width > measuredWidth)
            width = measuredWidth;


        Log.e("measured",String.valueOf(measuredWidth));


        // Draw grid
        double onePixelInSecs = pixelsToSeconds(1);
        boolean onlyEveryFiveSecs = (onePixelInSecs > 1.0 / 50.0);
        double fractionalSecs = mOffset * onePixelInSecs;
        int integerSecs = (int) fractionalSecs;
        int i = 0;
        while (i < width) {
            i++;
            fractionalSecs += onePixelInSecs;
            int integerSecsNew = (int) fractionalSecs;
            if (integerSecsNew != integerSecs) {
                integerSecs = integerSecsNew;
                if (!onlyEveryFiveSecs || 0 == (integerSecs % 5)) {
                    canvas.drawLine(i, 0, i, measuredHeight, mGridPaint);
                }
            }
        }

        // Draw waveform
        for ( i = 0; i < width; i++) {
            Paint paint;

            if (i + start >= mSelectionStart &&
                    i + start < mSelectionEnd) {
                paint = mSelectedLinePaint;
             //   paint.setColor(color);
            } else {
                drawWaveformLine(canvas, ((widths/width)*i), 0, measuredHeight,
                        mUnselectedBkgndLinePaint);
                paint = mUnselectedLinePaint;
            }
            drawWaveformLine(
                    canvas, ((widths/width)*i),
                    ctr - mHeightsAtThisZoomLevel[start + i],
                    ctr + 1 + mHeightsAtThisZoomLevel[start + i],
                    paint);


            if (i + start <= mPlaybackPos) {
                Paint mPaint = new Paint(paint);
                mPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
                drawWaveformLine(
                        canvas, ((widths/width)*i),
                        ctr - mHeightsAtThisZoomLevel[start + i],
                        ctr + 1 + mHeightsAtThisZoomLevel[start + i],
                        mPaint);

            }

             if (i + start == mPlaybackPos) {
                Paint mPaints = new Paint(paint);
                mPaints.setColor(Color.RED);
                drawWaveformLine(
                        canvas, ((widths / width) * i),
                        ctr - mHeightsAtThisZoomLevel[start + i],
                        ctr + 1 + mHeightsAtThisZoomLevel[start + i],
                        mPaints);
            }

        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.waveformDraw();
        }
    }}
   private void computeIntsForThisZoomLevel() {
        int halfHeight = (getMeasuredHeight() / 2) - 1;
        mHeightsAtThisZoomLevel = new int[mLenByZoomLevel[mZoomLevel]];
        for (int i = 0; i < mLenByZoomLevel[mZoomLevel]; i++) {
            mHeightsAtThisZoomLevel[i] =
                    (int)(mValuesByZoomLevel[mZoomLevel][i] * halfHeight);
        }
    }

}
```

***CustomAdapter class***

```
public class CustomWavePlayAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements WaveformView.WaveformListener {

ViewHolder holder;
Context mContext;
SoundFile mSoundFile;
boolean mLoadingKeepGoing;
boolean mFinishActivity;
String mTitle, mArtist;
Handler handler = new Handler();
Button pla, pause;
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
boolean ismIsPlaying;
int k = 0;
int j = 0;
TextView tv;
boolean runningWave = false;
ArrayList<String> mFilePath;
int totalLinesInWave = 0;
int count =0;
int myPos = 0;
private float mDensity;
private File mFile;
private String mFilename;
private long mLoadingLastUpdateTime;
private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
private Thread mLoadSoundFileThread;
private Thread mRecordAudioThread;
private Thread mSaveSoundFileThread;
private boolean mIsPlaying;
private SamplePlayer mPlayer;
private String mInfoContent;
private int mWidth;
private int mMaxPos;
private int mStartPos;
private int mEndPos;
private boolean mStartVisible;
private boolean mEndVisible;
private int mLastDisplayedStartPos;
private int mLastDisplayedEndPos;
private int mOffset;
private int mOffsetGoal;
private int mFlingVelocity;
private int mPlayStartMsec;
private int mPlayEndMsec;
private Handler mHandler;
private Handler myHandler = new Handler();

public CustomWavePlayAdapter(Context mContext, ArrayList<String> mfilePath){

    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.mFilePath = mfilePath;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mFilePath.size();

}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void waveformTouchStart(float x) {

}

@Override
public void waveformTouchMove(float x) {

}

@Override
public void waveformTouchEnd() {

}

@Override
public void waveformFling(float x) {

}

@Override
public void waveformDraw() {
    mWidth = holder.waveformView.getMeasuredWidth();
    if (mOffsetGoal != mOffset) {
        // updateDisplay();
    } else if (mIsPlaying) {
        //   updateDisplay();
    } else if (mFlingVelocity != 0) {
        //     updateDisplay();
    }
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


    if (convertView == null) {

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        mHandler = new Handler();

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(
                Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sound_files_items, null);
        holder.waveformView = (WaveformView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.waveformList);
        holder.button = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.playList);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
        myPos = position;

        final Uri uri = Uri.parse(mFilePath.get(position));
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();


        loadGui();
        loadFromFile(position);
        holder.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                runningWave = true;
                if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
                {
                    Log.e("adapter array",String.valueOf(uri));
                    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(mContext, uri);
                    //                mediaPlayer.prepare();
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, String.valueOf(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                    Log.e("length", String.valueOf(holder.waveformView.totalLines));

                }
                ismIsPlaying = true;

                if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                    playWaveAnimation(k);
                }

            }
        });
  }


    return convertView;
}

private void loadGui() {
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) mContext
            .getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    mDensity = metrics.density;
    holder.waveformView.setListener(this);

   if (mSoundFile != null && !holder.waveformView.hasSoundFile()) {
        holder.waveformView.setSoundFile(mSoundFile);
        holder.waveformView.recomputeHeights(mDensity);

    }

}

private void loadFromFile(int position) {
    mFilename = mFilePath.get(position);

    Log.e("check count", String.valueOf(count++) + ":" + String.valueOf(myPos)  + ":" + mFilename);

    mFile = new File(mFilename);

    SongMetadataReader metadataReader = new SongMetadataReader(mContext, mFilename);
    mTitle = metadataReader.mTitle;
    mArtist = metadataReader.mArtist;

    String titleLabel = mTitle;
    if (mArtist != null && mArtist.length() > 0) {
        titleLabel += " - " + mArtist;
    }
  //  setTitle(titleLabel);

    mLoadingLastUpdateTime = getCurrentTime();
    mLoadingKeepGoing = true;
    mFinishActivity = false;
    mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog( mContext);
    mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
    mProgressDialog.setTitle("Loading...");
    mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    mProgressDialog.setOnCancelListener(
            new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
                public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                    mLoadingKeepGoing = false;
                    mFinishActivity = true;
                }
            });
 //   mProgressDialog.show();

    final SoundFile.ProgressListener listener =
            new SoundFile.ProgressListener() {
                public boolean reportProgress(double fractionComplete) {
                    long now = getCurrentTime();
                    if (now - mLoadingLastUpdateTime > 100) {
                        mProgressDialog.setProgress(
                                (int) (mProgressDialog.getMax() * fractionComplete));
                        mLoadingLastUpdateTime = now;
                    }
                    return mLoadingKeepGoing;
                }
            };

    // Load the sound file in a background thread
    mLoadSoundFileThread = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                mSoundFile = SoundFile.create(mFile.getAbsolutePath(), listener);

                if (mSoundFile == null) {
                    mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                    String name = mFile.getName().toLowerCase();
                    String[] components = name.split("\\.");
                    String err;
                    if (components.length < 2) {
                        err = mContext.getResources().getString(
                                R.string.no_extension_error);
                    } else {
                        err = mContext.getResources().getString(
                                R.string.bad_extension_error) + " " +
                                components[components.length - 1];
                    }
                    final String finalErr = err;
                    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            showFinalAlert(new Exception(), finalErr);
                        }
                    };
                    mHandler.post(runnable);
                    return;
                }
                mPlayer = new SamplePlayer(mSoundFile);
            } catch (final Exception e) {
                mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                e.printStackTrace();
                mInfoContent = e.toString();
              /*  runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {

                    }
                });*/

                Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        showFinalAlert(e, mContext.getResources().getText(R.string.read_error));
                    }
                };
                mHandler.post(runnable);
                return;
            }
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
            if (mLoadingKeepGoing) {
                Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        finishOpeningSoundFile();

                    }
                };
                mHandler.post(runnable);
            } else if (mFinishActivity) {

            }
        }
    };
    mLoadSoundFileThread.start();

}

private void finishOpeningSoundFile() {
    holder.waveformView.setSoundFile(mSoundFile);
    holder.waveformView.recomputeHeights(mDensity);

}

private void showFinalAlert(Exception e, CharSequence message) {
    CharSequence title;
    if (e != null) {
        Log.e("Ringdroid", "Error: " + message);
        Log.e("Ringdroid", getStackTrace(e));
        title = mContext.getResources().getText(R.string.alert_title_failure);
     //   setResult(RESULT_CANCELED, new Intent());
    } else {
        Log.v("Ringdroid", "Success: " + message);
        title = mContext.getResources().getText(R.string.alert_title_success);
    }

    new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext)
            .setTitle(title)
            .setMessage(message)
            .setPositiveButton(
                    R.string.alert_ok_button,
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                            int whichButton) {
                            ((Activity)mContext).finish();
                        }
                    })
            .setCancelable(false)
            .show();
}

private long getCurrentTime() {
    return System.nanoTime() / 1000000;
}

private String getStackTrace(Exception e) {
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(writer));
    return writer.toString();
}

public void playWaveAnimation(int i) {
    k = i;

    final int intervalTime = 60;


    totalLinesInWave = holder.waveformView.totalLines;

    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            if (runningWave){

                //Display Data here
                if (k < totalLinesInWave ) {
                    holder.waveformView.setPlayback(k);
                    holder.waveformView.invalidate();
                    playWaveAnimation(++k);
                    Log.e("k value", String.valueOf(k));
                }

                if (k==totalLinesInWave){
                    k = 0;
                    runningWave = false;
                }



            }
        }
    }, intervalTime);
}

public void pauseWaveAnimation(int s) {

    j = s;
    if (j < totalLinesInWave) {

        Log.e("j value in pause",String.valueOf(j));
        holder.waveformView.setPlayback(j);
        holder.waveformView.invalidate();


    }
}
```